# Percent sign in .bat file not working with powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I already have an alternative solution, but I'm just curious about how it might be possible to get this command to work in a batch file.

```bash
REM RUN FROM A .BAT FILE
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('POWERSHELL -C "Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_(%I.%M%p)""') DO SET "CUR_DATE=%%A"
ECHO %CUR_DATE%
```

The `%` signs after `-UFormat` seem to cause the command to not work within a batch file.

I tried various combinations with:

```
%%
`
'
"
""
{
```

Comment: %% will escape a % in a .bat file

Comment: Making the appropriate escapes, ```@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-Date -UFormat \"%%Y-%%m-%%d_(%%I.%%M%%p)\"" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "CUR_DATE=%%G"```.

Comment: There's always the option to use a powershell script instead.

Comment: Of course @js2010, but you need to remember that doing, without invoking it using cmd/batch, usually requires an admin to pre-configure the OS, in order to run them directly. Many users don't have that pre-configuration.

Comment: powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file script.ps1 (the executionpolicy is only for unknowningly running a script like through an email attachment)

Comment: But @js2010, you are essentially running a command line to execute a script. It doesn't matter therefore, if the user wishes for that command line to be in a clickable batch file as opposed to, for instance, a clickable shortcut, or worse, typed into a GUI or CLI interface. It seems to me that 'batch hate', in this case is unjustified when the 'anger' should be with the default OS restriction. Clearly what was posted was only a snippet of something larger, and forcing a complete rewrite of the omitted content, to another script type is IMO a step too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to needing to double up the percent signs in a batch file, you'll also need to use both single and double quotes in the powershell command so that the interpreter doesn't incorrectly end one section prematurely. Since single quotes and double quotes are both significant in regular `for /f` loops, you'll need to use the `usebackq` option to use backticks to indicate that you're calling a command.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`powershell -c "Get-Date -UFormat '%%Y-%%m-%%d_(%%I.%%M%%p)'"`) do set "cur_date=%%A"
echo %cur_date%
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (short of just using a powershell script), using the [.net date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8).  Single quotes are easier to deal with in a bat file.  Parentheses are special to powershell.

```
powershell get-date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd_(HH.mmtt)'
```

Output:

```
2023-06-10_(12.22PM)
```